# Renaming session table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-storage

I have a Rails 2.3.2 application and I am using database for storing sessions.

Using 'rake db:sessions:create' creates the `session` table that holds the session id and related data.

My requirement is that I want to rename the session table to 'custom_session` and want my rails application to use this renamed table to update session data.

Is it possible in rails ?

Thanks

Comment: Your Ruby version is more than seven years old. I suggest to update to at least Rails 4.2, because your version has known security issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work on your version of Rails but try:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.table_name = 'custom_session'
```

cf https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store